# Changing the format of videos for mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile, content-management-system

**Hello, I would like to know how can i do to call a video on mobile and  in mode desktop
that you can use?
I have two videos a video is for desktop and i want you when you arrive in mobile change the format of the video.**
am working with php and javascript and mediaelements

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use css3 @media?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp